# Dovecot bouncing non-existent users (ignoring postfix aliases)

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

Recently configured postfix to use the dovecot lda as I wanted to use sieve. Got that working a few days ago but noticed that I wasn't getting any emails to aliases.

Aliases were working previously and are in /etc/postfix/vmaps.

Been Googling like mad all morning but I must be caffeine deficient and can't see how to make Dovecot deal with Postfix aliases before checking its dovecot users.

main.cf

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf -m "${EXTENSION}"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 104857600
myhostname = carson.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
policy-spf_time_limit = 3600s
readme_directory = no
recipient_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = carson.example.com ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_invalid_hostname,reject_non_fqdn_hostname,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_non_fqdn_recipient,permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination,check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf,reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/valid_senders, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = EXPORT
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = example.com
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaps
virtual_minimum_uid = 1000
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

dovecot config:

```
# 2.2.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.11.0-19-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS ext4
auth_mechanisms = plain login cram-md5
mail_debug = yes
mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%d/%n/Maildir
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date ihave
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  args = username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/shadow
  driver = passwd-file
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
protocols = imap pop3 sieve lmtp
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!LOW:!SSLv2:ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
userdb {
  args = username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/users
  driver = passwd-file
}
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = sieve
  postmaster_address = postmaster@example.com
}
protocol lda {
  deliver_log_format = msgid=%m: %$
  mail_plugins = sieve
  postmaster_address = postmaster
  quota_full_tempfail = yes
  rejection_reason = Your message to <%t> was automatically rejected:%n%r
}
protocol imap {
  imap_client_workarounds = delay-newmail
  mail_max_userip_connections = 10
}
protocol pop3 {
  mail_max_userip_connections = 10
  pop3_client_workarounds = outlook-no-nuls oe-ns-eoh
}
```

Comment: Is your problem solved? I have the same one.